# ¿Cargar un componente dinamicamente en Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Problema: Necesito cargar dinamicamente un componente en un modal pero que el modal a la vez acepte html, cosa que si le pongo el ViewContainerRef creo que solo aceptaria componentes y no solo html

Avance: He probado varios codigos de ejemplo y mayormente el contenido del componente va cargado el componente padre y no en el div que esta adentro del componente ..

Alguna ayuda por favor?

Solucion temporal: Puse 2 modal uno para html personalizado y otros para el componente y que lo cargue estaticamente , se que no es la solucion adecuada pero me aguanta ..

Si alguien tiene la solucion por favor comentarla ..

Comment: la respuesta no va en la pregunta, sino en la zona de respuestas

Comment: Entiendo pero no es la respuesta es un avance a la solución.